# Presence status on custom contacts dissapears after short time

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I made my own `SyncAdatper` to add contacts of my app to contacts on the phone.
Everything is working now (picture, status, custom action, etc) except for presence status.

According to google:

> Since presence status is inherently
>   volatile, the content provider may
>   choose not to store this field in
>   long-term storage.

So, I dont know how to keep the presence on the contacts all the time.
The code for updating the presence inside the cursor is

```
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.DATA_ID, c.getLong(1));
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS, status);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS_RES_PACKAGE, "ar.com.indiesoftware.ps3trophies");
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS_LABEL, R.string.app_name);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS_ICON, R.drawable.alltrophies);

builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.PROTOCOL, Im.PROTOCOL_CUSTOM);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL, "PS3SyncAdapter");
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.IM_ACCOUNT, username);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.IM_HANDLE, username);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.PRESENCE, ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.AVAILABLE);

builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS_TIMESTAMP, System.currentTimeMillis());
operationList.add(builder.build());
```

The green dot appears but If I leave the contacts screen and return in a short period of times (seconds), "sometimes" the green dot is not there anymore.

Is there something I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when your application is stopped by the OS, it is no longer pushing a presence status.